# Connecting to mysql with Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm trying to connect to mysql database with zend framework but it's unable to connect.
i followed up zend documentation and some other tutorial on how to connect to mysql but it's give's me an error on this line "$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();"

Error Message :

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Post\Model\PostTable
```

global.php

```
return array(
'db' => array(
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:dbname=zend;host=localhost',
    'driver_options' => array(
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
        => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
    ),
),);
```

local.php

```
 return array(
'db' => array(
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
),
```

);

PostController.php

```
public function getPostTable() {
    if (!$this->postTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->postTable = $sm->get('Post\Model\PostTable');
    }
    return $this->postTable;
}
```

//module/Post/src/Post/Model/PostTable.php

```
<?php
namespace Post\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;

class PostTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
  protected $table ='tbl_post';

   public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
{
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
    $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Post());
    $this->initialize();
}

public function fetchAll()
{
    $resultSet = $this->select();
    return $resultSet;
}
}
```

Comment: In your Module.php you should have 'Post\Model\PostTable'  injecting the table. Did you do that?

Comment: @dixromos98 No i didn't thanks :) it's working now

Comment: Good to know :). Should i post the comment as answer so you can accept it as a solution?

Comment: yes you can @dixromos98

Comment: ok posted the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Module.php you should have 'Post\Model\PostTable' injecting the table

good luck :)

Comment: you could explain better this answer please.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Please find out more here: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, think that it is obvious that 'Post\Model\PostTable' is not defined either at all, or where it should be.

Where is 'Post\Model\PostTable' defined in your codebase? How does that compare to ZF2's rules?

Comment: I see you updated your question but, '//module/Post/src/Post/Model/PostTable.php' seems suspect. (I will assume the // was a typo) And the Post/src/Post would appear to be the issue. Try moving your code to Post/ instead of Post/src/Post